# Javascript help - audio play waveform of random Wav/mp3

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have 2 different codes, each works well on its own. 
I've managed to combine them but lost functionality I needed. 
In essence, I'm trying to:
1. Grab a random mp3 or wav (from list)
2. Play it with a wavesurfer visual
3. Show play/stop button
4. a link to download (from same list, but different source)

With the code below I have these issues (as you can see here - http://writeasongtoday.com/test3/):
1. There's a text "Object object" appears from nowhere
2. Play/Stop doesn't work 
3. I had to delete the slink line (from #4 above), couldn't find a way to implement it

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white">


<div id="quote">   </div>


    <div id="waveform"></div>
<script>
     (function() {
 var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
 waveColor: 'darkorange',
 progressColor: 'purple',
    barWidth: '1',
    height: '100',
    fillParent: 'true',
    normalize: 'true',
      splitChannels: true,
    pixelRatio: '1'
});
      var quotes = [
        {
          qtext: "5", slink: "http://gumroad.com/2"
        },
        {
    qtext: "7",
          slink: "http://gumroad.com"
        }
      ];

      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<h1>' + quote.qtext + '</h1>' +
wavesurfer.load(quote.qtext + '.wav'),
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play(); 
    
   +  '<p><a href="' + quote.slink + ' ">I Want It</a></p>';

});        

       })(); 



</script>

   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause(quote.qtext + '.wav')">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    Play
  </button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the [object object] text is coming because you are appending the object with the heading h1, remove the `+` sign between the innerHTML and wave....`load`

Comment: @Bhansa, thanks! I removed it and the 'object' disappeared. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">


<div id="quote">   </div>


    <div id="waveform"></div>
    <script>
      (function() {
  var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
  waveColor: 'darkorange',
  progressColor: 'purple',
    barWidth: '1',
    height: '100',
    fillParent: 'true',
    normalize: 'true',
      splitChannels: true,
    pixelRatio: '1'
});
      var quotes = [
        {
          qtext: "5", slink: "http://gumroad.com/2"
        },
        {
      qtext: "7",
          slink: "http://gumroad.com"
        }
      ];

      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<h1>' + quote.qtext + '</h1>'
   +  '<p><a href="' + quote.slink + ' ">I Want It</a></p>';
wavesurfer.load(quote.qtext + '.wav');
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();

});        

       })(); 



</script>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause(quote.qtext + '.wav')">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    Play
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.pause();">pause</button>

</body>
</html>
```